# Merge and order 2 lists of different objects in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, linq, list

I have collections of 2 different types - let's call them     Cars and     Trucks. Both share base class Vehicle, which has property Passengers.

I want to merge them into a single collection ordered by that property. E.g., merge Cars and Trucks  and order by Passengers.

How should I do this?

Comment: I considered casting Cars and Trucks back to Vehicles, ordering Vehicles by Passengers, then TryCast() each Vehicle to Car or Truck. But that seems clunky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386979.aspx) Linq method to combine two lists.

```
Dim vehicles = cars.cast(Of Vehicle)().Concat(trucks.cast(Of Vehicle)())
Dim orderedVehicles = vehicles.OrderBy(Function(v) v.Passengers).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use LINQ and you're using .NET 4, it's easy:

```
Dim vehicles List<Vehicle> vehicles = _
    cars.Concat(Of Vehicle)(trucks).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Passsengers).ToList()
```

If you're not using .NET 4 (and therefore can't take advantage of generic covariance) you'll need to use [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx):

```
Dim vehicles = cars.Cast(Of Vehicle)() _
                   .Concat(trucks.Cast(Of Vehicle)) _
                   .OrderBy(Function(x) x.Passsengers) _
                   .ToList()
```

(Apologies for the transient C#-isms.)

... and if you're not using .NET 3.5, it becomes slightly more painful. (Doable, but messy.)